# No error occurs while adding an xml element which is not defined in the DTD?

Tags: xml, dtd

I am writing an internal DTD, the browser is checking just if the XML document is WELL FORMED, I am not getting any validation errors - what's the issue?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE note 
[
<!ELEMENT note (to+,from,heading,body)>
<!ELEMENT to (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT from (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT heading (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT body (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST from age CDATA #REQUIRED>
]>
<note>
<from>Jani</from> 
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Answer (score 0):

The XML parsers used in browsers are pretty limited in functionality, and as far as I'm aware they don't support DTD-based validation. In fact I think they ignore the DTD entirely, they don't do entity expansion either.